# How to get states and cities under a specific country - google map api

Tags: laravel, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Im still figuring how to use google map api's, I want to get all locations in my country (nigeria) and then put it in a dropdown, an example is something like jiji.ng, when trying to search they have a drop down with info of places, states etc in Nigeria, when the user searches it filters the locations, i tried typing in 'United State of America' & it showed me nothing because it is limited to Nigeria only, that is exactly what i want, check out jiji.ng pls, just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Google map is not really needed in doing this, You can download the list of places from [Geonames](http://www.geonames.org/export/) then you can use it within your app (To my understanding, its free maybe only some licences)